# VHDL signal driving

Tags: signals, driver, vhdl

I need to drive [11:0] data to two different entities at the same time.One of them is a band pass and other high pass. However, change in filter coefficients of HPF is changing the output of band pass filter.Both of these entities have only clock and reset as common inputs.please suggest suitable VHDL scheme for driving these two entities.(general approach to drive a data[n:0] to two different entities sharing common clock)

Comment: Please show the code you have created so far; that will make it much easier to give a useful answer that applies to your specific question.

Comment: To the downvoter: Please provide a short comment for the reason to downvote, since that will help newcomers to improve their questions.

Comment: Can you please draw a block diagram from the intended setup?

Comment: Write a testbench and simulate. Trace out what's happening on the internal signals in simulation. That will lead you to the problem and allow you to test your fix.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

module 1 and module 2 are independently processed and given to Digital analog converters.Independently designing for module 1(without module2 or viceversa) have expected outputs. But when given both modules given for the design, the output gets corrupted.Only common feature for two modules is clock.Does this mean signal driven from 1st 12 bit register can only drive one register(12-bit) at a time?